# How do you remove specific parts of a result in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a result with like so:

```
ups12345
ups09876
```

I would like just this:

```
12345
09876
```

I've come unsuccessful finding a function in my 30 minutes of searching.

Comment: What Database are you working on? Oracle or MySQL? can't be both. O.o Bit more details would be useful too, currently you've got nothing to go on regardless.

Comment: Start with [`substring()`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php).

Comment: What is the structure - three letters followed by digits? Variable number of letters and digits, delete the letters? Please make your question as specific as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use substr in mysql and Oracle

```
 SELECT SUBSTR(your_column,4,100) from you _table ;
```